# SDWebImage clear cache for image while scrolling?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiscrollview, ios6, sdwebimage

Can anyone please enlighten me how to clear cache while scrolling through images?
i m using SDwebImage package.It is working till 110 photos after that it giving memory receive warning and getting crash i have tried following method also but no success:

```
SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];
```

[imageCache clearMemory];
[imageCache clearDisk];
[imageCache cleanDisk];``

after this code it scroll 10 more photo after that get crash.

Answer (score 0):

try [imageCache release]; or autorelease while initiating or try writing in

```
-(void)dealloc
{
   [super dealloc];  
  [imageCache release];
}
```